# HTML selection API - adding <ul> elements to range

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selection-api

We have the following HTML document:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <p id="par1">Paragraph1</p>
    <ul id="list1">
        <li>Item1.1</li>
        <li>Item1.2</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="par2">Paragraph2</p>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li>Item2.1</li>
        <li>Item2.2</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="par3">Paragraph3</p>

    <script>
        let list1 = document.getElementById('list1');
        let list2 = document.getElementById('list2');

        let range = document.createRange();
        range.setStartBefore(list1);
        range.setEndAfter(list2);

        document.getSelection().addRange(range);
        console.log(document.getSelection());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also available as a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RyfAyikamNOnSki2DY9d?p=preview).

Basically, we are trying to create a selection range that begins right before ul#list1 and ends right after ul#list2, where both lists are completely included. Using this selection, we will want to drag this selection in another drop zone.

Visually, this seems to work correctly. However, looking at the logged document selection, we see that the anchorNode is the 1st li of ul#list1 and the focusNode is p#par3. This means that when setting the drag content, ul#list1 is not included and p#par3 is mistakenly included.

Is there a way, using the selection API, to accomplish what we want?

Comment: Selection API does not specify the ‘correct’ behaviour, meaning it will vary between browsers. In Firefox, for example, your selection will more or less match your expectations, but WebKit and Blink will normalise the hell out of it (moving both points where they see fit). Good news is browsers will also never try and drop invalid fragments onto your drop zone. The question is whether or not what they drop will match what you want. Have you tried? What did you get?